# where does not contain array

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

my below query looks ok to me but im not sure why im getting errors.

The error is "the best overload for string.containts(string) has some invalid arguments". what am i missing here?

Thanks

```
string[] strHiddenESXi = {"Internal","Support","Archived"};
            var tblvirtualservers = from d in db.tblVirtualServers.Include(t => t.ChangeLog).Include(t => t.ESXi)
                                    where (!d.ESXi.ESXiName.Contains(strHiddenESXi)) && d.ESXiID != 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] strHiddenESXi = {"Internal","Support","Archived"};
var tblvirtualservers = from d in db.tblVirtualServers.Include(t => t.ChangeLog)
 .Include(t => t.ESXi)
 where (!strHiddenESXi.Contains(d.ESXi.ESXiName)) && d.ESXiID != 20
```

You have to use Contains with strHiddenESXi that is an Array.

Can you try?

```
string[] strHiddenESXi = {"Internal","Support","Archived"};
var tblvirtualservers = from d in db.tblVirtualServers.Include(t => t.ChangeLog)
 .Include(t => t.ESXi)
 where (!strHiddenESXi.Any( a=> d.ESXi.ESXiName.Contains(a) )) && d.ESXiID != 20
```

Comment: this seems to be doing an exact match as opposed to a contains for some reason?

Comment: Does your ESXiName contain comma separated items?

Comment: No, for example I want to hide internal1 internal2 and internal3... but i can see 1 2 and 3 i cant see Archived, which works, Thanks

Comment: Can you try new update and let me know if that works, I don't have anyway to test that.